# Should a method be 'fired' from within a property?

Tags: mvvm, properties

My application uses the MVVM pattern. My `TextBox` is bound to a property of my ViewModel (type string).

When ever the content of the `TextBox` changed via the user typing, I want to perform some validation.

So, currently, my code is

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding XmlContentAsString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and my ViewModel has this property and field:

```
        private string _xmlContentAsString;
        public string XmlContentAsString
        {
            get { return _xmlContentAsString; }
            set
            {
                if (_xmlContentAsString == value)
                    return;

                _xmlContentAsString = value;
                PerformValidiationLogic(value);//This is where I am unsure
            }
        }
```

Now, this works but, and I don't know why, I don't like this! It some how feels 'hacked' to include the method in the property.

Can some one please tell me if this is the correct approach when using the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 1):

There's different type of validations.
For simplistic validating string lengths or allowed characters etc you can use DataAnnotations and put the validation in attributes on your properties. You'll need to include
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

then for example to keep string to 9 characters:

```
    [StringLength(9)]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get
        {
            return stringValue;
        }

        set
        {
            this.stringValue = value;
        }
    }
```

Then there is validation that is a bit more complex and is effectively enforcing your business logic. 
There seem to be many views on how to do this. Ideally it should belong on the model, so that the validation can be reused, but obviously called via the viewmodel.

Personally I will put method calls in the property setters occasionally, to me thats the whole reason for having the ability to create setters and getters - otherwise there's very little point in having anything other than auto properties.

But if it's complex or asynchronous then you can hit issues.
I'd be very careful doing it with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, as that means you'll be firing it every character.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you perform validation logic on the value, but what would be the result of the validation if it fails?  Typically you would want to notify the user of a validation failure.  If that is the case, then I suggest IDataErrorInfo (examples can be found here:

http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/).

If you plan on overriding the value without notifying the user, then validating in the setter is acceptable (though still not a fan for more personal reasons).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion thats the correct approach. I would write a base class for your ViewModel that contains a method that sets the property, call PropertyChanged and validate if some validation rule is attached to that property.

For example:

```
public abstract class ValidableViewModel
{
    private List<ValidationRule> _validationRules;

    public ValidableViewModel()
    {
        _validationRules = new List<ValidationRule>();
    }

    protected virtual void SetValue<T, T2>(Expression<Func<T>> expression,
                                           ref T2 backend, T2 value)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T2>.Default.Equals(backend, value))
            return;

        backend = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(expression);

        Validate(expression.Name, value);
    }

    protected void Validate(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        foreach(var validationRule in _validationRules)
        {
            if(validationRule.PropertyName == propertyName)
                validationRule.Execute(value);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not complete, there is missing a lot. But it could be a start ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't advise putting so much logic in your property.  I would use a command bound to an event, ie the lostfocus event of the textbox, and perform your validation there.

I would use something like this:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding XmlContentAsString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LostFocusCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>           
    </TextBox>
```

then have a command in your view model that is LostFocusCommand wiht your validation logic.
I use mvvm-light and can give a more detailed example for that.  (you will need to include the blend interactivity declaration at the top of your xaml)